Why are `given ... with { ... }` and `given ... = new { ... }` working differently?
Here's an example that makes me scratch my head:
// A trait that transforms A -> B

trait Transformer[A, B] {
  def transform(a: A): B
}

// A trait that creates a Transformer which would encode `From` to `To`,
// involving an intermediate type defined as `Intermediate`.
// Basically it represents a chain of From (-> Intermediate) -> To conversion.

trait DoubleEncoder[From, To] {
  type Intermediate
  
  def transformer(using Transformer[From, Intermediate], Transformer[Intermediate, To]): Transformer[From, To]
}


// Now we define a chain of Int -> X -> Y

class X(i: Int)
class Y(x: X)

given Transformer[Int, X] = X.apply _
given Transformer[X, Y] = Y.apply _



// And DoubleEncoder for that chain

given DoubleEncoder[Int, Y] = new DoubleEncoder[Int, Y] {
  type Intermediate = X
  
  override def transformer(using t1: Transformer[Int, X], t2: Transformer[X, Y]): Transformer[Int, Y] =
    new Transformer { def transform(i: Int): Y = t2.transform(t1.transform(i)) }
}



// With DoubleEncoder defined we can create a transformer of P (-> Intermediate) -> Q out of defined DoubleEncoders

given [P, Q](using de: DoubleEncoder[P, Q])(using Transformer[P, de.Intermediate], Transformer[de.Intermediate, Q]): Transformer[P, Q] =
  de.transformer



summon[Transformer[Int, Y]].transform(1) // But then boom.

(Scastie)
The last line fails with quite an obscure message:

Weirdly, if I change one line it starts working as intended:
given DoubleEncoder[Int, Y] = new DoubleEncoder[Int, Y] {
 // ...

to
given DoubleEncoder[Int, Y] with {
 // ...


What gives? Why didn't it work in the first version? And what difference is there between the first and the second version?
EDIT: Also, even if the type signature of the second version preserves the dependent type information, wouldn't it have been stripped out of the last given statement? It summoned them with de: DoubleEncoder[P, Q] not de: DoubleEncoder[Int, Y] { type Intermediate = X }. Why did it still make a difference?

The first version removes the path-dependent type from the public signature, thus implicit resolution can't work at all. The second one, preserves that path, which allows the resolution to tie all the pieces together.

You'd need: given DoubleEncoder[Int, Y] { type Intermediate = X } = new ...

Thanks, feel free to make it an answer. By the way I've edited OP to add a follow-up question of it.

@mateusz-kubuszok Unfortunately it says another obscure error saying "abstract givens cannot be annonymous". I guess it's a syntax issue?

Maybe, adding a type helper fixes this - https://scastie.scala-lang.org/qHGS7Ec4Q7SxUaieRnJHsw

If you refine the type of the given to DoubleEncoder[Int, Y] { type Intermediate = X }, like this:
given DoubleEncoder[Int, Y] { type Intermediate = X } = new DoubleEncoder[Int, Y] {
  type Intermediate = X
  
  override def transformer(using t1: Transformer[Int, X], t2: Transformer[X, Y]): Transformer[Int, Y] =
    new Transformer { def transform(i: Int): Y = t2.transform(t1.transform(i)) }
}

then "works on my machine", at least with 3.3.1:
trait Transformer[A, B] {
  def transform(a: A): B
}

// A trait that creates a Transformer which would encode `From` to `To`,
// involving an intermediate type defined as `Intermediate`.
// Basically it represents a chain of From (-> Intermediate) -> To conversion.

trait DoubleEncoder[From, To] {
  type Intermediate
  
  def transformer(using Transformer[From, Intermediate], Transformer[Intermediate, To]): Transformer[From, To]
}


// Now we define a chain of Int -> X -> Y

class X(i: Int)
class Y(x: X)

given Transformer[Int, X] = (i: Int) => X(i)
given Transformer[X, Y] = (x: X) => Y(x)

// And DoubleEncoder for that chain

given DoubleEncoder[Int, Y] { type Intermediate = X } = new DoubleEncoder[Int, Y] {
  type Intermediate = X
  
  override def transformer(using t1: Transformer[Int, X], t2: Transformer[X, Y]): Transformer[Int, Y] =
    new Transformer { def transform(i: Int): Y = t2.transform(t1.transform(i)) }
}

// With DoubleEncoder defined we can create a transformer of P (-> Intermediate) -> Q out of defined DoubleEncoders

given [P, Q](using de: DoubleEncoder[P, Q])(using Transformer[P, de.Intermediate], Transformer[de.Intermediate, Q]): Transformer[P, Q] =
  de.transformer


@main def entry(): Unit = 
  summon[Transformer[Int, Y]].transform(1) // no boom, works fine

That being said, all this "double encoder" with path dependent types looks unnecessarily complex. Here is a more straightforward way of doing the same:

Delete DoubleEncoder
Delete abstract member types
Delete the double using-parameter lists
Delete path dependent de.Xyz-types

trait Transformer[A, B] {
  def transform(a: A): B
}

class X(i: Int)
class Y(x: X)

given Transformer[Int, X] = (i: Int) => X(i)
given Transformer[X, Y] = (x: X) => Y(x)

given [P, I, Q](using pi: Transformer[P, I], iq: Transformer[I, Q]): Transformer[P, Q] with
  def transform(p: P): Q = iq.transform(pi.transform(p))

@main def entry(): Unit = 
  summon[Transformer[Int, Y]].transform(1) // works fine
  println("ship it")


Also note that at least in this simplified example, your Transformer has collapsed into a simple Conversion:
class X(i: Int)
class Y(x: X)

given Conversion[Int, X] = (i: Int) => X(i)
given Conversion[X, Y] = (x: X) => Y(x)
given chainConversions[X, Y, Z](using xy: Conversion[X, Y], yz: Conversion[Y, Z]): Conversion[X, Z] with
  def apply(x: X): Z = yz(xy(x))

@main def entry(): Unit = 
  summon[Conversion[Int, Y]](1) // also works fine
  println("ship it")


